# Why URL rewriting with .htaccess points to index?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect `example.com/test` to `example.com/good.php` keeping my nice www rewriting, yet it allways points me to `index.php`, why?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([^\.]+))\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^http://www\.(([^\.]+))\.com/test$ good.php [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule doesn't work on the full URL, it just works on the path, so your RewriteRule for good.php can be as simple as `RewriteRule ^test$ good.php [R=301,L]`

Comment: By the way, the first RewriteCond + RewriteRule is going to auto-redirect any requests for www.example.com to example.com (i.e. removing the www.), so later rules will never receive any requests for URLs starting with "www." in any case.